# Is there a way to set an alias as the project support email in firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, alias, google-workspace

I have a user `myname@mydomain` with a GSuite email that I have added as an owner to the firebase project, and I can add that as the project email. However I would like to set `help@mydomain` as the project email, where `help@` is an alias that points to `myname@`. It is not letting me select this email, and when I tried to add `help@` as a user, nothing happened and I cannot see it as a user. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways I was able to accomplish this. The first is to create a google group, such as "myproject [at] googlegroups dot com", then add that email to my firebase project users and permissions using the "Viewer" permission.

The second it to create an email alias on my hosting account, such as "support at myproject dot org" that forwards to my regular email address that I want to keep hidden, then invite that email to firebase project. There were 2 problems with this. One is I don't want to maintain additional google user accounts. The other is that it required me to add this user as "Editor" rather than "Viewer" permission. You can add it as editor, assign it to be your general support account for the project, then drop the permissions back down to Viewer.

Either way should solve your problem - not sure which method I prefer yet.